# Slow down or pause NSAnimationContext

Tags: cocoa, nsanimationcontext

I have an NSAnimationContext (just a scrolling view) that I would like to slow down and/or pause whenever the cursor enters the view. I have already implemented the detection for when this happens - now I just need to figure out how to slow down the animation that is already in process. I have figured out how to do this with CALayers - but I need to use the animator proxy unable to use several AppKit views within this animation so Core Animation will not work. Does anyone know how to do this? Is there a way to keep track of NSAnimationContexts and then change them later on?

Here is a subsection of my code, The first block is cyclicly called. Everytime one agnation completes the next will begin.

```
[NSAnimationContext runAnimationGroup:^(NSAnimationContext *context){
    context.duration = pixels/speed;
    [[currentTweetView animator] setFrame:endRect];
} completionHandler:^{
    [currentTweetView removeFromSuperview];
    currentTweetView = nil;
    [self nextAnimationWithAnimationIndex:currentIndex];
}];
```

Here is the code in the mouseEntered: method. Whenever this is called, neither completionHandler is ever called and the app freezes.

```
[NSAnimationContext runAnimationGroup:^(NSAnimationContext *context){
    [[[self.subviews objectAtIndex:0] animator] setFrame:finalRect];
    context.duration = 100.0;
} completionHandler:^{
    NSLog(@"done");
}];
```

Also, is there any way to end an NSAnimationContext early and not call the completion handler?

Answer (score 0):

I think if you just set the property via the `animator` proxy again, under a different `NSAnimationContext,` it will replace the animation that was in progress.  This would be analogous to retargeting the animation (e.g. to a new destination).

Comment: I have just tried this, the app freezes and the second animation never takes place and the app just freezes.

Comment: Can you try leaving out the completion handlers? Does that change anything? Also, in the second case, don't you want to set the duration before doing the `-setFrame:`?